# Java List sort and group using Stream

Tags: java, list, arraylist, group-by

I have a `List<Records> =`

```
[
    {"studentId": "001", "date": "20180705", "courseId": "CS220", "score": "80"},
    {"studentId": "001", "date": "20180702", "courseId": "CS320", "score": "75"},
    {"studentId": "001", "date": "20180704", "courseId": "CS330", "score": "90"},

    {"studentId": "002", "date": "20180703", "courseId": "CS640", "score": "95"},
    {"studentId": "002", "date": "20180628", "courseId": "CS530", "score": "80"},
    {"studentId": "002", "date": "20180701", "courseId": "CS545", "score": "90"},

    {"studentId": "100", "date": "20180708", "courseId": "CS542", "score": "80"},
    {"studentId": "100", "date": "20180629", "courseId": "CS240", "score": "97"},

    ... 
]
```

How can I group the objects by same `studentId` and just keep the one which has highest score in list? like following:
`List<Records> =`

```
[
    {"studentId": "001", "date": "20180704", "courseId": "CS330", "score": "90"},

    {"studentId": "002", "date": "20180703", "courseId": "CS640", "score": "95"},

    {"studentId": "100", "date": "20180629", "courseId": "CS240", "score": "97"},

    ... 
]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  I would suggest that you iterate through the list once and save the highest score for each studentId using a Map, and the iterate a second time and remove the elements that do not match what is stored in the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `Stream` to collect the value. You can find an example on [Baeldung -- Guide to Java 8 groupingBy Collector](http://www.baeldung.com/java-groupingby-collector)

> 2.8. Getting the Maximum or Minimum from Grouped Results

This could be used like :

```
records.stream()
    .collect(
         Collectors.groupingBy(
             Record::getStudentId, 
             Collectors.maxBy(Compartor.comparingInt(Record::getPoint))
         )
    );
```

The map returned will have each `studentId` as a key and the instance with the maximum value. Example using a POJO :

```
class POJO {
    String name;
    int value;

    //getters
    //toString //POJO [%name% %value%]
}
```

And the quick test :

```
Map<String, Optional<POJO>> map = Stream.of(
            new POJO("A", 1), new POJO("A", 2), new POJO("A", 10),
            new POJO("B", 8), new POJO("B", 4),
            new POJO("C", 4),
            new POJO("D", 4), new POJO("D", 1), new POJO("D", 2)
            ).collect(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(
                            POJO::getName, 
                            Collectors.maxBy(
                                    Comparator.comparingInt(POJO::getValue)
                            )
                    )
            );

    System.out.println(map);
```

> {A=Optional[POJO [A 10]],
>   B=Optional[POJO [B 8]],
>   C=Optional[POJO [C 4]],
>   D=Optional[POJO [D 4]]}

Comment: Thank you so much, that's what I want!  Stream is more efficient than iterating a map twice, thanks!

Comment: I have added an example @haohuily.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with java8's stream.

```
    records.stream()
.collect(Collectors.toMap(Records::getStudentId ,Records::getScore,(s1,s2)->Math.max(s1,s2)))
```

The 3rd param (merge function) of the toMap method always selects the greater score value.

Comment: Nice solution ! The problem with this is you create a `Map<String, Integer>`, you loose the instance information. If you also want to know the course and date of this best result, you will need to search the student again.